# c# select Columns from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, subset

**EDIT:**

I also get the same error doing this:

```
var table = table.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "col1", "Col2");
```

**Original Post:**

I would like to select a subset of columns from a DataTable. Other solutions on SO suggest this solution:

```
DataView view = new DataView(dataTable); 
DataTable dtQueryTable = view.ToTable(false, new string[] { "col1", "col2" });
```

Where col1 and col2 are the columns I want to select.

However, I'm getting this error: Column 'col1' does not belong to underlying table ''.

The columns definitely exist. What I am missing?

Comment: What does `dataTable.DefaultView.ToTable` do?

Comment: You can also use .Copy() on DataTable and remove columns using .Columns.Remove("col3")

Comment: Thanks .Copy() is interesting. But I have 50+ columns, so removing 48 columns in this way isn't that clean.

Comment: Just to be clear, your DataTable has columns named `col1` and `col2`?

Comment: Are you try view.ToTable(true, "col1", "col2");?

Comment: Yes, col1 and col2 do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code.

```
var table = table.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "col1", "Col2");
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I've tried this too, but get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can  simply do like below.

**Altered code from your post:**

```
DataView view = new DataView(dataTable); 

DataTable dtQueryTable = view.ToTable(testtbl,false,"col1", "col2");
```

//testtable = anytablename

**Below is the syntax for better understanding:**

```
public DataTable ToTable(
    string tableName,
    bool distinct,
    params string[] columnNames
)
```

Hope it will helpful for you,kindly let me know your thoughts and feedbacks
thanks
karthik